# How to self-send an email with XAMPP-Mercury Mail using php

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, thunderbird, mercury-mta

I've been searching a lot, but can't really find what i exactly need.

Im running a shop-online using XAMPP, and what i want is send emails to the customers with their order but using a specific function.

What this fuction does, is to hide some characters (for security purpose) on the email sent to customers. So i've made the function (looking on internet), but i want to test it now.

This is my function (if it's wrong, i'd really appreciate some help):

```
<?php
 function xtc_hide_iban ($iban) {

$length = strlen($iban);
$lchars = substr($iban,0 ,5);
$rchars = substr($iban, -5);
$iban_hidden = $lchars.str_repeat('*',$length-10).$rchars;
return $iban_hidden;

}
?>
```

I think it's pretty obvious what i try to do, but i will still explain it:

> Get the $iban from customers, and show only the first and last 5
>   characters when the email is sent e.G
>
> **Your IBAN is 'DE123************56789'**

So, for now i can send emails from Mercury mail server to 'root@localhost',account i made on thunderbird, (it's the only account that worked for me, because any other with the same server, like 'anyname@localhost' didn't work or couldn't be created, and those who were create with imap before couldn't access to the inbox *"could not connected to server, connection refuse"*, anyway this works with POP3)

Following what i looked before, is that somehow and somewhere i can put a *.php on Mercury folder so i will get a template of how to send the mails (headers, subject,body,etc).

My main question is ***how and where to do that? make a test php file to make sure my code is doing what i want to do***

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$lchars = $iban.substr(0 ,5);` and `$rchars = $iban.substr(-5);` aren't going to work. It should be `$lchars = substr($iban, 0, 5);`

Comment: Thanks @RobinRijkeboer, i had my code as you write it before, but changed after seen some other examples on internet, so i got confused.
Let me know if you see any other mistake